# Selecting intersection of two queries with a single map table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, intersection, intersect

I'm sure this is easy, but so help me I can't figure out why I can't return the right result.

Pretty standard setup, I have a ref_product table, a ref_tagmap table and a ref_tag table...

```
CREATE TABLE `ref_product` (
`id` DOUBLE ,
`name` VARCHAR (765),
`familyid` DOUBLE ); 

INSERT INTO `ref_product` (`id`, `name`, `familyid`) VALUES('264','Old Red Fixture 1','4');
INSERT INTO `ref_product` (`id`, `name`, `familyid`) VALUES('30206','Modern Red Fixture 2','405');


CREATE TABLE `ref_tag` (
`TagID` DOUBLE ,
`TagName` VARCHAR (150)); 

INSERT INTO `ref_tag` (`TagID`, `TagName`) VALUES('103','Modern Contemporary');
INSERT INTO `ref_tag` (`TagID`, `TagName`) VALUES('131','Red');

CREATE TABLE `ref_tagmap` (
`MapID` DOUBLE ,
`tagid` DOUBLE ,
`containertype` VARCHAR (45),
`containerid` DOUBLE ); 

INSERT INTO `ref_tagmap` (`MapID`, `tagid`, `containertype`, `containerid`) VALUES('17035','131','PROD','264');
INSERT INTO `ref_tagmap` (`MapID`, `tagid`, `containertype`, `containerid`) VALUES('17747','131','PROD','30206');
INSERT INTO `ref_tagmap` (`MapID`, `tagid`, `containertype`, `containerid`) VALUES('31959','103','PROD','30206');
```

Querying these tables using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ref_product.familyid,ref_tag.tagid
FROM (ref_tag,ref_product)
JOIN ref_tagmap AS mt2 ON  mt2.containerid=ref_product.id
AND  mt2.containertype='PROD'
AND  mt2.tagid=ref_tag.tagid 
AND ref_tag.tagname='red'
```

correctly returns all of the product familyids that have the tag 'red' mapped to them. Similarly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ref_product.familyid,ref_tag.tagid
FROM (ref_tag,ref_product)
JOIN ref_tagmap AS mt1 ON mt1.containerid=ref_product.id
AND mt1.containertype='PROD'
AND mt1.tagid=ref_tag.tagid 
AND LCASE(ref_tag.tagname)='modern contemporary'
```

correctly returns the product familyids that have the tag 'modern contemporary' mapped to them. QUESTION IS, HOW DO I RETURN A LIST OF ONLY THE PRODUCT FAMILYIDS THAT HAVE BOTH TAGS MAPPED TO THEM?

I'm trying this, and it returns empty:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ref_product.familyid,ref_tag.tagid
FROM (ref_tag,ref_product)
JOIN ref_tagmap AS mt2 ON  mt2.containerid=ref_product.id
AND  mt2.containertype='PROD'
AND  mt2.tagid=ref_tag.tagid 
AND ref_tag.tagname='red'
JOIN ref_tagmap AS mt1 ON mt1.containerid=ref_product.id
AND mt1.containertype='PROD'
AND mt1.tagid=ref_tag.tagid 
AND LCASE(ref_tag.tagname)='modern contemporary'
```

I have to assume I'm missing something fundamental here...feeling dense. Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this is to ensure that the number of distinct items in the `tag` table is equal to the number of tags you wish to isolate.
Example:

```
SELECT p.familyid
FROM   ref_product p
       JOIN ref_tagmap tm ON tm.containerid=p.id
       AND tm.containertype='PROD'
       JOIN ref_tag t ON t.tagid = tm.tagid
       AND t.tagname IN ('red',
                         'modern contemporary')
GROUP BY p.familyid 
HAVING count(DISTINCT t.tagid) = 2;
```

In action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f377e/7

Comment: Bernie, thanks for the reply...but I'm not sure this will help. I'm trying to isolate how to structure this little clause...which is part of a much, much larger query with a dozen or so conditions (and several more joined tables and I'm already grouping on something else.) So I'm trying to understand if there is a way to strictly limit the results returned to only those that have both tags mapped. Any other way to skin this cat?

Comment: I'll add that I really don't need to return the tag_id or tag_name, just the product.familyid that is tagged by all passed tags.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please note that you can use this query as a subquery in your outer query. Either join to it (some call this a derived table) or use it as a correlated subquery (in the WHERE clause of the outer query).

Comment: Bernie, not sure if you're still following this thread, but I just had a chance to revisit this outstanding issue and, as suspected, rewriting the logic as a subquery pushed the execution time from milliseconds to over ten minutes (this has been my experience with almost all MySQL subqueries). Including your grouped by code in any manner beyond a simple where in (subquery) is beyond me, despite my research into correlated queries and derived tables...could I trouble you for an example? Do you think these variations on the code would perform acceptably?